# Parsing all the doubles from a string C#

Tags: c#, string, parsing, windows-phone-8, double

I actually have strings formed like this one:

```
 { Desc = Marketcap, Val = 
    1,270.10 BTC
    706,709.04 USD
    508,040.00 EUR
    4,381,184.55 CNY
    425,238.14 GBP
    627,638.19 CHF
    785,601.09 CAD
    72,442,058.40 JPY
    787,357.97 AUD
    7,732,676.06 ZAR
 }
```

I'd need to parse out all the doubles in it, and I am actually stuck with that. How may I do that?

EDIT: I actually know how many numbers I am going to parse, that's fixed, like in that string (that's just the number that changes). I don't need the notation, neither (like BTC, USD, etc)

Comment: Parse it to extract the text after `Val = ` and before `}`, then split it by spaces into an array. Since you know the format, all your numbers will be in the even entries (`[0], [2], [4]`) and the currency types in the odd entries (`[1], [3], [5]`)

Comment: what was the problem you are facing?whts ur approach?

Comment: Do the values *always* use commas for the thousands separators and dots for the decimal separators? Also, you should strongly consider using `decimal` instead of `double` - it's more appropriate for currenct data. Also, are your values on separate lines within the string?

Comment: I actually know how I could do that this way, just scanning it "cell by cell", till the end of the array. I wanted to know if there is a less brainless way to act :D

Comment: @JonSkeet, yeah, the format is ALWAYS that one, it's not going to change :)

Comment: @guido1993 are you sure your string is in this format or is it a valid json string from *cryptocoincharts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data actually looks like this:

```
var data = new
{
    Desc = "Marketcap",
    Val = @"1,270.10 BTC
706,709.04 USD
508,040.00 EUR
4,381,184.55 CNY
425,238.14 GBP
627,638.19 CHF
785,601.09 CAD
72,442,058.40 JPY
787,357.97 AUD
7,732,676.06 ZAR",
};
```

(Because what you have in your question is unclear.)

Then you could do this:

```
var query =
    from d in data.Val
        .Split(
            Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray(),
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    select decimal.Parse(
        d.Split(' ')[0],
        System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-au"));

decimal[] array = query.ToArray();
```

That gives you:

[image: Array of Decimals]

Also, you want to parse this as `Decimal`, not `Double`, as `Decimal` is accurate for financial calculations and `Double` can lead to rounding errors.

Comment: I would specify a `CultureInfo` explicitly, given the commas and dots...

Comment: I actually thought Decimal and wrote Double :)

Comment: Well, my request was actually how I could get all those Decimals into an array of decimals, declared like this one: decimal[] array = new decimal[]{};

Comment: @JonSkeet - I've added explicit `CultureInfo`. Cheers.

Comment: @guido1993 - I can't read in your question where you ask for an array, but I'll make the change to my answer.

Comment: I am sorry, I thought I mentioned that :)

Comment: Strangely enough, what I am getting when I run your code is an array containing just the [0] field, the other will throw an ArrayOutofBoundException if attempted to be read, and the numbers are losing their decimal part (so instead of 1270.10 I am getting 127010)

Comment: @guido1993 - I've re-run my code and it runs perfectly. Does my code run correctly for you when you use my input data? (Please make sure that the second line of currency values starts at column 0 in your editor.)

Comment: I suppose that the issue on my side comes out because of Windows Phone 8 SDK, since it looks like it doesn't contain the GetCultureInfo method

Answer (score 1):

This uses a Regex to match blocks of text that start with a digit, contains a comma or period and ends with a digit. Seems to work for me just fine.

You can use `double` or `Decimal` depending on what you need.

```
[TestClass]
public class UnitTests
{
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestMethod1()
    {
        string str =
            @"{ Desc = Marketcap, Val = 1,270.10 BTC 706,709.04 USD 508,040.00 EUR 4,381,184.55 CNY 425,238.14 GBP 627,638.19 CHF 785,601.09 CAD 72,442,058.40 JPY 787,357.97 AUD 7,732,676.06 ZAR }";
        MatchCollection matches = Regex.Matches(str, @"\d[\d,\.]+\d");
        double[] values = (from Match m in matches select double.Parse(m.Value)).ToArray();
        Assert.AreEqual(10,values.Length);
        Assert.AreEqual(1270.10,values[0]);
    }
}
```